# In Okular, how can I use compose keys (or even <ctrl>+<shift>+u unicode entry)?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, okular

I'm annotating a PDF, using Okular, which seems to work quite well for sending to Windows users running Adobe reader (unlike some alternatives).

Compose keys combinations don't work at all.  Instead, when I hit `<AltGr>` (my compose key) Okular displays "⁻" (apparently that's *U+207B Superscript Minus*, but not the same as the superscript hyphen-minus I get with `<AltGr> ^ -`), so for ° (`<AltGr> o o`,  degree sign) I get "⁻oo" in the annotation input box, and "oo" as the displayed annotation.

This may or may not be related: If I paste in a non-keyboard unicode symbol, it may or may not display in the annotation. § (section mark) does, but ₂ (subscript 2) doesn't (though it does appear in the annotation input/edit box). The superscript minus I mention above also shows only in the input, not the displayed annotation.  Worst of all, Greek letters don't show up in inline annotations.

This is Xubuntu 20.04 LTS, with Okular installed via apt. I've confirmed that this isn't a sneaky snap install - `apt list okular*` returns a few packages with the main `okular/focal` being version 4.19.12; `snap list | grep okular` (and indeed `snap list` and reading the whole output) shows nothing